# Python Durable Functions struggling get customStatus of Blob URL

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions

I have a routine that rates thousands of orders so it takes a bit to run. I am trying to set it up so the front end UI that calls the routine can check the progress of it, so I decided to do it through an Azure Durable Function. I have a lot of experience with other Azure Functions, but the Durable Function is new to me. Initially I created a dictionary that had orders that were done and orders that were not yet done, and then returned it using:

```
context.set_custom_status(status_update)
```

This worked for testing small orders, but the problem became that for large samples, it exceeded the 16kb limit that Azure allows for JSON text. So I found a suggestion to write the updates to a Blob and then send the Blob URL to the custom status. This is where I have been banging my head against the wall for.

I have tried different ways of doing this, but the problem I always run into is either 1. The blobs try to save as the same name and crash. 2. The custom status is just Null. I am guessing it has something to do with multiple instances running, but this type of function is new to me so I'm potentially confused by it and not really sure the best way to handle it.

This code is all in my DurableFunctionsOrchestrator function. Here is one way I tried doing it while letting the "Update" function handle dropping the file in the blob.

```
       for order in orders:
           print(order)
           custom_update = yield context.call_activity('Update', order)
           context.set_custom_status(custom_update)
           # expected this custom_update to return the URL for the blob, but the custom update is Null
```

I also tried it this way where I let the orchestrator function save the blob:

```
        for order in orders_list:
            order_status = yield context.call_activity('Update', order)
            print(order_status)
            rated_orders.append(order)
            not_rated_orders = list(filter(lambda order: order not in rated_orders, orders_list))
            status_update.update({'Rated Orders' : rated_orders, 'Orders to process' : not_rated_orders})
            blob_name = f'test_{order}.json'
            blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string, container_name=container, blob_name=blob_name)
            blob.upload_blob(json.dumps(status_update))
            custom_update = {'Blob Url' : str(blob.url)}
            print(f"{blob_name} : {custom_update}")
            context.set_custom_status(json.dumps(custom_update))
```

This method will update the custom Status, but will crash shortly after with this error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
> Functions.DurableFunctionsOrchestrator. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: Orchestrator > > function 'DurableFunctionsOrchestrator' failed: The specified blob already exists.
> RequestId:911649d3-401e-011b-23ef-532bf4000000
> Time:2021-05-28T18:29:52.5057612Z
> ErrorCode:BlobAlreadyExists
> Error:None.

So even though I'm trying to save the order as the Blob name, and the orders are all unique, it is still trying to process that order again, my guess is because it is a different instance running.

How can I get the program to only process an order once, save an updated status of what orders have been processed to a Blob, and return the URL of the blob in the customStatus when I request a GET update on the Durable Function Orchestrator?